# A kind of martingale convergence theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales

We know from Doob's (super-)martingale convergence theorem that $X_n \to X_\infty$ almost surely, if $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a super-martingale
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}|F_n) \le X_n
$$
adapted to some filtration $(F_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and is bounded from below in a suitable sense (i.e. $\sup_k \mathbb{E}(\max(-X_k, 0)) < +\infty$) . In particular we consider the special case where the filtration is the sigma algebra generated by the process itself, i.e. we have
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}|\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_n)) \le X_n.
$$

> The question is, can we prove something in the case where we only have
>   $$
> \mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}|X_n) \le X_n.
> $$

Comment: You didn't state the (super)martingale convergence theorem correctly. There are supermartingales which do not converge almost surely. (You mention the missing assumption at the very end of your question, but as it is written now it is quite misleading...)

Comment: fixed. I tried to improve the readability by not having technical assumptions in the main text but apparently it didn't work as intended.